# php - Logging: use the same object in multiple classes

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, parent

I've been sitting on this for ages now and cannot figure out a way that satisfies me.

My problem:
I got a parent class and various subclasses.
In the constructor of the parent, a new object is created (amongst other things). This object is from my log file class. It is stored in a protected variable.

In the parent class, the log keeping is not a problem, everything is done according to plan.

If I want to use the object in a subclass, I cant get it to work. I just cant access it.
I tried a function in the parent class in order to return the object, this didnt work either.

I am at a loss here.

This is the constructor of the parent:

```
function __construct() {
...   
 $this->reg_log_file = new log_file(bef_registration::REG_LOG_NAME, bef_registration::REG_LOG_KEEPING);
...
}
```

In order to create a new entry, in the parent class, the following is sufficient:

```
$this->reg_log_file->entry('start log');
```

In a child class, this would lead to an error:

> Call to a member function entry() on a non-object

After googling and reading for hours, I still havent come up with a proper way of doing this.

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: In Child class, should you not be calling that object using a reference to parent? `parent::`. Protected members should be visible in child classes according to PHP Manual `Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes`

Comment: Here is something you might have missed: a logger should be a decorator, not a dependency.

Comment: I thought so as well, but every single way I've tried, I couldnt exist the variable.

When I print_r the object, the variable seems to be empty, I dont know why.

teresko, I dont know what you are trying to say. I am not relying on it, I simply want to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `parent::__construct();` in the body of every child contstructor and the log object will be instantiated and visible in all inherited subclasses.

Comment: Doesnt this mean that the object is newly created every time?

Comment: If you create subclass object all constructors (of child and of all his parents) will run just once.